# python(3.23) Implementation back propagation, type error on list

Tags: python, neural-network, typeerror, backpropagation

I get a type error when trying to run my back propagation on a neural net when trying to train it to do 'and' pattern.

just do be clear, I'm not requesting anyone read or review my code..

I'm just giving a bunch of it, because I'm not really certain what's causing this error.

I included a bunch of prints in the backprop function because I've been testing it.

my source is posted in its entirety at: [my github](https://github.com/clampz/cpat_project).

here's what shows up in the command line:

```
$python main.py
enter a filename: params.dat
max_iterations: 100, error_threshhold: 0.001000, netError: 1.001000, n_iterations: 0
eval of while loop: True
1backProp iteration = 0, netError = 1.001000
2backProp iteration = 0, netError = 1.001000, inputsForWeightChangeLoop:
[0, 1]
3backProp iteration = 0, netError = 1.001000, inputsForWeightChangeLoop:
[0, 1]
4backProp iteration = 0, netError = 1.001000, inputsForWeightChangeLoop:
[]
5backProp, oldInputsWeightChange:
[0, 1]
6backProp, inputNN.layers[j].neurons[k]:
<neuralNet.neuron object at 0x7f405e97be90>
8backProp, y(stuff):
0.7615941559557649
9backProp, y(stuff):
0.7615941559557649
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 51, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__": main()
  File "main.py", line 41, in main
    backProp(inputNeuralNet, dStruct['input'], dStruct['target'], dStruct['max_iterations'], dStruct['error_threshhold'], dStruct['rateOfLearning'])
  File "/home/nab/Documents/cpat_project-master/propagate.py", line 66, in backProp
    inputsForWeightChangeLoop.append(float(y(oldInputsWeightChange, inputNN.layers[j].neurons[k])))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Basically, it's giving a type error where I'm trying to collect the outputs of one layer so that during the next iteration of my weight change loop, I can calculate the error valus of the neurons and then change the weights.

My question, is basically how do I calculate the outputs of these neurons without getting this type error.

Here's the back propagation code:

```
"""
backProp takes a neural network (inputNN), a set of input training values (input),
a number of maximum allowed iterations (max_iterations), and a threshold for the
calculated error values, this last value is used as a way to tell when the network
has been sufficiently trained. back propagation is an algorithm for training a
neural network.
"""

def backProp(inputNN, input, targets, max_iterations, error_threshhold, learningRate):
    n_iterations = 0 # counter for the number of propagation loops
    netError = float(error_threshhold + 1.0)
    print('max_iterations: %d, error_threshhold: %f, netError: %f, n_iterations: %d' % (max_iterations, error_threshhold, netError, n_iterations))
    print('eval of while loop: %s' % (n_iterations < max_iterations and netError > error_threshhold))
    while ((n_iterations < max_iterations) and (netError > error_threshhold)):
        print('1backProp iteration = %d, netError = %f' % (n_iterations, netError))
        for i in input:
            y = inputNN.update(i) # present the pattern to the network
            outputLayerError = errorGradientOutputLayer(sum(y), targets[n_iterations]) #calc the error signal, assumes that output layer has only 1 node.
            newWeights = [] # to collect new weights for updating the neurons
            inputsForWeightChangeLoop = i # this is actually to collect outputs for computing the weight change in hidden layers, which are then used as inputs
            print('2backProp iteration = %d, netError = %f, inputsForWeightChangeLoop:' % (n_iterations, netError))
            print(inputsForWeightChangeLoop)
            counter = 0 # used for a condition to compute the error value in the hidden layer above the output layer.
            layersFromOut = list(range(0, inputNN.n_hiddenLayers + 1)) # this is in order to get the reverse of a list to do a backwards propagation,  + 1 for input layer
            layersFromOut.reverse() # reverses the list
            error2DArray = [] # this collects error values for use in the change of the weights
            for j in layersFromOut: # for every layer, starting with the hidden layer closest to output.
                for k in range(0, inputNN.layers[j].n_neurons): # for every neuron in the layer
                    if counter != 0: # if the neuron isn't in the hidden layer above the output
                        error2DArray.append(errorGradientHiddenLayer(k, j, inputNN, error2DArray[j + 1]))  # compute the error gradient for the neuron
                    else:
                        error2DArray.append(errorGradientHiddenLayer(k, j, inputNN, [outputLayerError])) # '' same but for the hidden layer above the output layer
                counter += 1
            for j in range(0, inputNN.n_hiddenLayers + 2): # for every layer, + 2 in range for output and input layers.
                for k in range(0, inputNN.layers[j].n_neurons): # for every neuron in the layer
                    newWeights = []
                    for h in range(0, inputNN.layers[j].neurons[k].n_inputs): #for every weight in the neuron
#params for deltaWeight -- deltaWeight(float oldWeight, float learningRate, list[float] inputsToNeuron, list[float] errorValues, float derivitiveOfActivationFn)
                        newWeights.append(deltaWeight(inputNN.layers[j].neurons[k].l_weights[h], learningRate, inputsForWeightChangeLoop[h], error2DArray[j], derivActivation(inputsForWeightChangeLoop, inputNN.layers[j].neurons[k]))) # get the change in weight
                    inputNN.layers[j].neurons[k].putWeights(newWeights) #update the weights
                print('3backProp iteration = %d, netError = %f, inputsForWeightChangeLoop:' % (n_iterations, netError))
                print(inputsForWeightChangeLoop)
                oldInputsWeightChange = inputsForWeightChangeLoop # this is used to calculate the new inputs for the change in weight
                inputsForWeightChangeLoop = [] # clear it to re-populate
                for k in range(0, inputNN.layers[j].n_neurons): # for every neuron in the layer
                    print('4backProp iteration = %d, netError = %f, inputsForWeightChangeLoop:' % (n_iterations, netError))
                    print(inputsForWeightChangeLoop)
                    print('5backProp, oldInputsWeightChange:')
                    print(oldInputsWeightChange)
                    print('6backProp, inputNN.layers[j].neurons[k]:')
                    print(inputNN.layers[j].neurons[k])
                    print('8backProp, y(stuff):')
                    print(float(math.e**activation(oldInputsWeightChange, inputNN.layers[j].neurons[k]) - math.e**((-1) * activation(oldInputsWeightChange, inputNN.layers[j].neurons[k])))/float(math.e**activation(oldInputsWeightChange, inputNN.layers[j].neurons[k]) + math.e**((-1) * activation(oldInputsWeightChange, inputNN.layers[j].neurons[k]))))
                    print('9backProp, y(stuff):')
                    print(sigmoid(activation(oldInputsWeightChange, inputNN.layers[j].neurons[k])))
                    #print('7backProp, y(stuff):')
                    #print(y(oldInputsWeightChange, inputNN.layers[j].neurons[k]))
                    inputsForWeightChangeLoop.append(float(y(oldInputsWeightChange, inputNN.layers[j].neurons[k])))
                    #inputsForWeightChangeLoop.append(y(oldInputsWeightChange, inputNN.layers[j].neurons[k])) # calculate the new inputs
            n_iterations += 1
            errorVal = 0# sum unit for the net error
            for j in range(0, len(input)): # for every pattern in the training set
                for k in range(0, len(inputNN.layers[-1].n_neurons)): # for every output to the net
                    errorVal += errorSignal(targets[k], y[k])
            netError = .5  *  errorVal #calc the error fn for the net?
            print('5backProp iteration = %d, netError = %f' % (n_iterations, netError))
        #
    print('propagate finished with %d iterations and %f net error' % (n_iterations, netError))
    return
```

here's my function y, which may be a convoluted way to denote the output of a node:

```
"""
y takes a set of patterns or inputs (p), and a neuron (n) and returns the 
output for the specified node in the neural net. [keep in mind that the
input of some neuron is really in terms of the layer above it.]
"""
def y(p, n):
    if (len(p) != n.n_inputs): # if the node has a different number of inputs than specified in params, throw error.
        raise ValueError('wrong number of inputs: y(p, n) in propagate.')
    return sigmoid(activation(p, n))
```

and my sigmoid:

```
"""
sigmoid takes an activation value (activation) and calculates the sigmoid 
function on the activation value. [here I use the tanh function]
"""
def sigmoid(activation):
    return float(math.e**activation - math.e**((-1) * activation))/float(math.e**activation + math.e**((-1) * activation))
```

and finally, my activation:

```
"""
activation takes a neuron (n) and a set of patterns or inputs (p) and returns
the activation value of the neuron on that input pattern.
"""
def activation(p, n):
    activationValue = 0
    for i in range(0, len(p)):
        activationValue += p[i] * n.l_weights[i]
    activationValue += (-1) * n.l_weights[-1] # threshhold?
    return activationValue
```

I'm not really sure exactly how much of my code is needed, so I'll go ahead and include the entire neural net module below..

```
"""
  neuralNet.py
  4/21/13, 5:30p

"""

import sys
import random
import math
import propagate


class neuron():
    n_inputs = 0
    l_weights = []

    def __init__(self, numberOfInputs):
        self.l_weights = []
        self.n_inputs = numberOfInputs
        for i in range(0,(numberOfInputs + 1)): #for each input + threshhold
            self.l_weights.append(random.randint(-1,1))

    #
    def putWeights(self, weights):
        for i in range(0, len(weights)):
            self.l_weights[i] = weights[i]

class neuralNetLayer():
    n_neurons = 0
    neurons = []

    def __init__(self, numNeurons, numInputsPerNeuron):
        self.neurons = []
        self.n_neurons = numNeurons
        for i in range(0, numNeurons):
            #print('neuralNetLayer -> length of self.neurons: %d' % len(self.neurons))
            #print("neural net layer makes a neuron -> %d" % i)
            self.neurons.append(neuron(numInputsPerNeuron))

    def getWeights(self):
        weights = []
        for i in range(0, self.n_neurons):
            i_weights = []
            for j in range(0, len(self.neurons[i].l_weights)):
                i_weights.append(self.neurons[i].l_weights[j])
            weights.append(i_weights)
        return weights

class neuralNet():
    n_inputs = 0
    n_outputs = 0
    n_hiddenLayers = 0
    n_neuronsPerHiddenLyr = 0
    layers = []

    def __init__(self, numInputs, numOutputs, numHidden, numNeuronsPerHidden):
        self.layers = []
        self.n_inputs = numInputs
        self.n_outputs = numOutputs
        self.n_hiddenLayers = numHidden
        self.n_neuronsPerHiddenLyr = numNeuronsPerHidden
        #print('making input layer with %d neurons and %d inputs to the neurons' % (numInputs, numInputs))
        self.layers.append(neuralNetLayer(numInputs, numInputs))# make input layer
        for i in range(0, self.n_hiddenLayers):
            #print('making hidden layer with %d neurons and %d inputs to the neurons' % (numNeuronsPerHidden, numNeuronsPerHidden))
            self.layers.append(neuralNetLayer(numNeuronsPerHidden, numNeuronsPerHidden))# make hidden layers
        if numHidden > 0: # if you have hidden neurons, output will connect to them
            #print('making output layer with %d neurons and %d inputs to the neurons' % (numOutputs, numNeuronsPerHidden))
            self.layers.append(neuralNetLayer(numOutputs, numNeuronsPerHidden))
        else:
            #print('making output layer with %d neurons and %d inputs to the neurons' % (numOutputs, numInputs))
            self.layers.append(neuralNetLayer(numOutputs, numInputs))# make output layer connect to input layer

    #returns a list of the weights in the net
    def getWeights(self):
        weights = []
        for i in range(0, self.n_hiddenLayers + 1): #+ 1 because output layer
            for j in range(0, self.layers[i].n_neurons + 1):
                for k in range(0, self.layers[i].neurons[j].n_inputs + 1):
                    weights.append(self.layers[i].neurons[j].l_weights[k])
        return weights

    #replaces the weights in the net with the given values
    def putWeights(self, weights):
        counter = 0
        for i in range(0, self.n_hiddenLayers + 1):
            for j in range(0, self.layers[i].n_neurons + 1):
                self.layers[i].neurons[j].putweights(weights[i][j])

    #returns the number of weights in the net
    def getNumWeights(self):
        num = 0
        for i in range(0, self.n_hiddenLayers + 1):
            for j in range(0, self.layers[i].n_neurons):
                for k in range(self.layers[i].neurons[j].n_inputs + 1):
                    num += 1
        return num

    # given some inputs, returns the output of the net
    def update(self, inputs):
        if (len(inputs) != self.n_inputs):
            raise ValueError('wrong number of inputs: update() in neuralNet.')
        for i in range(0, self.n_hiddenLayers + 1): # I need to do this for every hidden layer + input layer.
            outputs = []
            for j in range(0, self.layers[i].n_neurons):
                if i != 0:# if current layer is not input layer
                    outputs.append(propagate.y(outputPriorLayer, self.layers[i].neurons[j]))
                else:
                    outputs.append(propagate.y(inputs, self.layers[i].neurons[j]))
            outputPriorLayer = outputs
        return outputs[0:len(self.layers[-1].neurons)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're defining yet another `y` variable in that method:

```
y = inputNN.update(i) # present the pattern to the network
```

I haven't looked at the source closely enough, but it seems like this variable is set only sometimes, which lets your code run fine part of the time. You have to choose another name that doesn't conflict with your `y` function.

Comment: changed the variable name and that was that. thanks for the help again!